# Amcharts - Increase gap between legend name & value

Tags: amcharts

In the graph generated with amcharts, the legend name & the value are overlapping. I've tried adding a non-breaking space to increase padding, added new line, added just spaces, tried many properties from the amcharts manual related to legend. None of these have helped thus far.

Could I please request ideas/the property (if one exists) to increase the distance between the legend name & it's value?

Comment: Correct answer would be: "yes". Ok just kidding. Sajids answer below seems like a working solution, although changing `valueWidth` should be sufficient.

Comment: but when i added space in right and left of my title as String into graph its worked and label legend and value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`valueWidth`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueWidth) property

```
"legend": {
  "autoMargins": false,
  "valueWidth": 90
},
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much Sajid.

Comment: I would like to achieve the same and I am using amchart 4. Amchart 4 doesn't have this property. How to get thsi resolved?